# CentOS6.7 で DHCP で IP を取得できない

Tags: linux, centos, network

- 動作環境
  CentOS 6.7

## 現状の問題点

NetworkManagerが起動している状態で

```
service network start
```

を実行してもネットワークが有効化されない。
エラーとしては

```
em1 の IP情報を検出中...[失敗]
```

とだけでて原因が明示されていない。

## 行った対応

centos にてNICが有効化出来ないときの対処方法を調べて以下を実行した。

1. /etc/udev/rule.d/70-persistant-net.rule を削除して再起動
   →　このファイルが存在しない
2. NetworkManagerを停止、ifcfg-em1 の記述からNM_CONTROLLED=no に設定してからどうようにネットワークを起動したが、IPアドレスが検出出来ずに失敗。
   →これはNetWorkManagerの管理下からはずしているので当然の事象
3. 上記2つを試した後、ip a コマンドを実行して、筐体で使えるNIC情報を調査したところ、em1 と em2 が存在時、em1 の IPv4のIPアドレスがそもそも認識されていない。
   nmcliコマンドを実行して、デバイスの状況を調査したところem1 がIPアドレス取得中のままで、結果としてIPアドレスを取得できていないところまで分かりました。

上記のようなCentOSでのNICの有効化のトラブルの場合、どういった対処が考えられるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いたします。

## 2015/12/08追記

```
#ifcfg-em1ファイル
HWADDR = 90:B1:C1:00:1F:2A
TYPE = Ethenet
UUID = 994eb0f8-5400-4dfe-beffd54aebd704d
ONBOOT = yes
BOOTPROTO = none
IPADDR = 172.20.21.74
DEFROUTE = yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL = yes
GATEWAY = 172.20.21.1
PREFIX = 24 

ip addrの結果
1: lo: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: em1: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state up qlen 1000 
    link/ether 90:b1:c1:00:1f:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172:20:21:74/24 brd 172:20:21:255 scope global em1
    inet6 fe80:92b1:1cff:fe00:1f2a/64scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: em2:<BLOADCAST, MULTICAST> myu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:b1:c1:00:1f:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

また

```
arping -D (同一セグメント内のIPアドレス)
```

を実行したところ

```
arping: unknown iface eth0
```

が返ってきました。

Comment: em1 に DHCP で IPアドレスを割り当てたいのですか？
em2 は DHCP または static で IPアドレスを割り当て済みで利用できているのでしょうか？
em1 と em2 が逆に認識されている可能性はないでしょうか。MAC アドレスで確認してください。

Comment: DHCPサーバーは同じネットワーク上にありますか？間にL3スイッチやルーターなどありませんか？

Comment: @take88  DHCPサーバーというものが用意されているかが現状わかっておりません。ただ、今回起動している筐体はマイダにスイッチがあることまでは確認済みです。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya em1にDHCPでIPアドレスを割り当てたいと考えております。em2はnmcliで確認した所、LANが接続されていないところまで確認しました。em1とem2が逆に認識されているとはどういった状況なのでしょうか？一度MACアドレスを確認してみます。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん。
　MACアドレスを確認した所、`/etc/sysconfig/network-sfcript/`以下にあるifcfg-em1のファイルに書かれているHWaddrの値（MACアドレス）がip aコマンドで使えるデバイスを表示した際にはem1にはlink/ether (ifcfg-em1のMACアドレス) という表示をされておりました。
　これはMACアドレスが正常に設定されているという認識で合っておりませうでしょうか。
　もしそうでない場合、どういった設定を行い、結果が得られると適切に設定されているということになるのでしょうか？

Comment: DHCPでIPアドレスを割り当てるにはDHCPサーバーが必用です。DHCPサーバーは同じネットワーク上に存在している必要があるのでネットワーク管理者に確認いただくか、ご自宅等でしたらブロードバンドルータがDHCPサーバーの機能を持っている場合もあります。ひとまず固定IPを設定してみてはいかがでしょうか。固定IPでつながれば NICの有効化に問題はなく、DHCPの問題だとはっきりしますので。

Comment: @take88 さん
ありがとうございます。
DHCPサーバーですが、今回立ち上げた筐体については同一ネットワーク内に外の筐体が動作しており、そちらはDHCPでネットワークに接続されているので、DHCPサーバーは動作しております。
固定IPで接続できるか確かめてみます。

Comment: @take88 さん
固定IPで設定してNICを起動してみたところ、NICの起動までは確認できたのですが、pingコマンドを通した時に
`From (スイッチのIPアドレス) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable`
という表示がされて外からpingでアクセスできません。同様にうちからpingでアクセスすることも現状できておりませんが、NICが起動していてこういった状況の場合どこを見ればよろしいでしょうか？
同一ネットワーク内でインターネットに接続されている筐体とサブネットマスク、ゲートウェイの設定は全て同様にしているにも関わらずつながっておりません。

Comment: 宛先ホストに到達できないようですね。ネットワーク構成が分からないのでなんとも言えませんがスイッチのarpキャッシュをクリアすると治る場合があります。あと em1 はリンクアップしてるか分かりますか？物理ポートのランプの状態を確認してください。またスイッチのIP、デフォルトゲートウェイのIPへPingをうつとどうなりますか。`/etc/udev/rule.d/70-persistant-net.rule` がないというのはファイル名を間違ってませんか？実際のファイルは「.rules」ですが書き間違いでしょうか。

Comment: @take88  さん
ありがとうございます。
`/etc/udev/rule.d/70-persistant-net.rule`
こちら打ち間違いです。`/etc/udev/rule.d/70-persistant-net.rules`のファイルは存在しません。
アドバイス頂いた確認事項を元に試してみます。

Comment: 物理ポート1=em1, 物理ポート2=em2 と人間は考えますが、筐体によっては逆に認識される(物理ポート1=em2)場合があります。そこを確認しておかないと、徒労に終わるかと思ったのです。

ifcfg-em1 の HWADDR は、Linux が(おそらくインストール時に)最初に認識したものがセットされているので、必ずしも物理ポート1 の MACアドレスとは限りません。筐体の仕様表を調べて物理ポートの MACアドレスと合っているかどうか。
または、物理ポート2 にケーブルがつながっていないなら、em1, em2 のうち Link Up している方("ip addr" で "state UP" の方)が物理ポート1 です。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
アドバイスありがとうございます。
現状ですが、`ip addr`コマンドで確認した所、筐体のポート１に接続した状態でem1がStateUPされておりましたので、ポート1がem1だと考えております。
この状態を確認した段階で再度networkを再起動しましたが、まだpingが通らないという状況が変わらずにおりますがこういった場合はあとどういった対処が考えられるのでしょうか。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
追記ですが、stateUPされているポートを確認して、LED点滅させてみたところ、LANが刺さっているポートが点滅しておりました。
stateUPされているポートには接続されておりますが、ネットには接続されていない状態です。

Comment: 質問文を編集して、ifcfg-em1 ファイルの内容、および、"ip addr" コマンド出力結果を追記してくださいませんでしょうか。
また、"arping -D (同一セグメント内のIPアドレス)" で MACアドレスの返答はありますでしょうか。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
ありがとうございます。
質問内容修正、追記させていただきました。調べた内容は以上になります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: "arping -I em1 -D (同一セグメント内のIPアドレス)" ではどうでしょうか。
また、Typo だと思いますが、「IPADDR=172.20.32.74」→「IPADDR=172.20.21.74」、「link/ether 90:b1:1c:00:1f:2a」→「link/ether 90:b1:c1:00:1f:2a」ですよね。
設定は特に問題はないと思います。ケーブルやスイッチ、ネットワーク側の問題ではないでしょうか。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
指摘いただいていた点はtypoです。申し訳ありません。
`arping -I em1 -D (同一セグメント内のIPアドレス) 'を実行したところ'arping: unknown iface (同一セグメント内のIPアドレス)'が返ってきました。ネットワーク側のトラブルの場合、どういったアプローチで調査していけばよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: arping のオプションで "-I (IPアドレス)" としていませんか？
オプションは順序どおりにする必要があります。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32652/discussion-between-taichi-yanagiya-and-tarotarotarroro)しましょう。

Comment: やり取り拝見しましたがDHCPの問題とはっきりしたようですね。今後も調査するのであれば、ネットワーク構成やDHCPサーバーの設定を書いてもらえると トラブルシューティングのお手伝いが出来るかもしれません。